# How to use query in a stored procedure in Visual Studio to get the ID from a table using the value in another column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2019, dapper

I am trying to use a value from a text field on a forum to fill another text field with the corresponding ID from a database table I have.

My procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGet_PersonId_byName]
    @PersonName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT dbo.People.ID
    FROM dbo.People
    WHERE dbo.People.Name = @PersonName;
END
```

I think the problem is how I call it, I need to get a string value to use in my text field.

This is the forum code:

```
private void PersonNameDropDownBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string NameToUse = PersonNameDropDownBox.Text;

    foreach (IDataConnection db in GlobalConfig.Connections)
    {
        PersonIDTextBox.Text = db.PersonIdLookup(NameToUse).PersonId.ToString();
    }
}
```

and this is the method

```
public PersonModel PersonIdLookup(string NameToUse)
{
    PersonModel OutPutModel;

    using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
    {
        var i = new DynamicParameters();
        i.Add("@PersonName", NameToUse);
        OutPutModel = connection.Query<PersonModel>("[Trial DB].dbo.spGet_PersonId_byName", i, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }

    return OutPutModel;
}
```

Sorry for the messy data but I am very new to all of this.

It won't build because I get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestingClassLibrary.PersonModel>' to 'TestingClassLibrary.PersonModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it won't build because i get this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestingClassLibrary.PersonModel>' to 'TestingClassLibrary.PersonModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i fixed the `@PersonName != @PatientName`

Comment: Every name is unique?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson which ones do you mean ?

Comment: If you can look up an ID based on a Name, then Name must be unique. Otherwise, if you had 2 people named John, you couldn't find the correct ID.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson in my case they are unique. The Execute Scalar method executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. The additional columns or rows are ignored

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be

```
private void PersonNameDropDownBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string NameToUse = PersonNameDropDownBox.Text;
            foreach (IDataConnection db in GlobalConfig.Connections)
            {
                PersonIDTextBox.Text = db.PersonIdLookup(NameToUse);
            }
        }
```

and

```
public string PersonIdLookup(string NameToUse)
        {
            string OutputId;
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
            {
                var i = new DynamicParameters();
                i.Add("@PersonName", NameToUse);
                OutputId = connection.ExecuteScalar<string>("[Trial DB].dbo.spGet_Person_byName",i,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            return OutputId;
        }
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGet_PersonId_byName]
    @PersonName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT dbo.People.ID
    FROM dbo.People
    WHERE dbo.People.Name = @PersonName;
END
```